# how to use ion-refresher inside a custom component

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework, ionic3

I need to place the ion-refresher inside a component.

I have a list which is identical in look and behavior, my list component should have refresher, infinite-scroll etc in that one component

I try to add ion-refresher to a custom component.

```
<ion-refresher (ionRefresh)="refreshList($event)">
    <ion-refresher-content></ion-refresher-content>
</ion-refresher>
```

but I  get this error:

```
Parse Error: No provider for Content
```

Answer (score 0):

Did u try?

```
<ion-content>
<ion-refresher (ionRefresh)="refreshList($event)">
    <ion-refresher-content></ion-refresher-content>
</ion-refresher>
</ion-content>
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned [here](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/issues/10540) and in the [docs](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/refresher) you need to put your refresher inside a `<ion-content>` tag.

```html
<ion-content>
  <ion-refresher (ionRefresh)="refreshList($event)">
    <ion-refresher-content></ion-refresher-content>
  </ion-refresher>
</ion-content>
```

Answer (score 0):

when we place ion-refresher inside ion-content, it creates extra space